# PubsubMessage publish_time gets saved as DatetimeWithNanoseconds

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to instantiate the following `PubsubMessage`:

```
        timestamp = Timestamp()
        timestamp.GetCurrentTime()
        message = pubsub_v1.types.PubsubMessage(
            data=b'{"id": 123}',
            attributes={"some_attribute": "abcd"},
            message_id="1",
            publish_time=timestamp,
    )
```

When I inspect the `timestamp` variable, it is of type `Timestamp` with `seconds` and `nanos` attributes, just as expected. However when I inspect `message.publish_time` I get a `DatetimeWithNanoseconds` object instead which does not have the aforementioned attributes so I get an error later in my code (because of [this line](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/commit/6b9eec81ccee81ab93646eaf7652139fc218ed36#diff-9d37cc3aaac018e0c394df450a873e66R112) in google-pubsub)

I've checked google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp) but I can't seem to find anything like this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems that when passing a `PubsubMessage` instance to the constructor of the `Message` class, you can actually do the following:

`message=message._pb`

I noticed this in [this line](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/6b9eec81ccee81ab93646eaf7652139fc218ed36/tests/unit/pubsub_v1/subscriber/test_message.py#L51) of the google-pubsub repo

By passing the message as its `._pb` attribute you don't get an exception when trying to access `message.publish_time.seconds` or `message.publish_time.seconds`. I'm not sure why this is the case but it solved my problem. I'll add an update if I find more info on this.

Comment: But I think this is being done so that they can look at the core data instead of the entire pubsub message.  If all you want is the core data, then you don't need to use a `PubsubMessage` object at all.  For instance, with [`ReadFromPubSub`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.29.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub), if you pass `with_attributes=False`, then you just receive `bytes`, not the full `PubsubMessage` object.  I hope that makes sense!